# re.search for a dictionary key and returning a value

Tags: python, python-re

New user in python.

I'm trying to make MX records readable by checking a dictionary.

This only returns the "else", but I can't find out why.

```
import re

mx_dict = {
    "l.google.com": "Google",
    "protection.outlook.com": "Outlook",
    "one.com": "One"
}

def mx_check(mx_record):
    for key, value in mx_dict.items():
        if re.search(key, mx_record):
            return value
        else:
            return mx_record

print(mx_check('aspmx.l.google.com.'))
```

Solution found, thank you @khelwood

```
import re
mx_class = {
    "l.google.com": "Google",
    "one.com": "One",
    "domenehost.no": "Domenehost"
}

def mx_check(mx_record):
    for key, value in mx_class.items():
        if re.search(key, mx_record):
            mx_record = value
    
    return mx_record

print(mx_check('mx2.pub.mailpod3-cph3.one.com.'))
```

Comment: Your loop always returns on the first iteration. If the first key it checks isn't found, it immediately returns `mx_record` and skips the rest of the loop. Move the `return mx_record` to after the loop.

Comment: Why not use `key in mx_record`?

Comment: `.` has special meaning in regular expressions. You should escape them if you want to match them literally. Otherwise, `one.com` will match `onexcom`

Comment: @Barmar Your second comment is exactly why I asked why OP is using regexes :)

Comment: @Barmar `'one.com' in 'mx2.pub.mailpod3-cph3.one.com.' == True`

Comment: @Altareos I misread your comment. I thought you were doing `mx_record in mx_dict`